# Cast Stringtype to ArrayType

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is it possible to cast a StringType column to an ArrayType column in a spark dataframe ?

`df.printSchema()` gives this

> Schema -> 
>   a: string(nullable= true)

Now I want to convert this to

> a: array(nullable= true)

Comment: You can't cast you have to split it

Comment: how can i split it . could you explain it  with an example?

Comment: would you care at least give a data sample ?

Comment: a = [{val1:"somevalue_x", val2:"somevalue_y"}, {val1:"someValue_z", val2:"someValue_v"}] , currently a is a string and i want it as an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [elisiah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3415409/eliasah) commented you have to split your string. You can use UDF:

```
    df.printSchema

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    val toArray = udf[Array[String], String]( _.split(" "))
    val featureDf = df
      .withColumn("a", toArray(df("a")))  

    featureDF.printSchema
```

Gives output:

```
root  
 |-- a: string (nullable = true)

root
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option to simply wrap any `column` in `functions.array`.

```
df.withColumn("a", functions.array(col("a")))
```